# Problems installing srilm 1.6.0 with llvm-gcc 4.x

Tags: c++, build, installation, nlp

## The problem

I am trying to build [SRI's Language Modeling tool](http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/), `srilm` version 1.6.0 on my mac, and coming across some fairly strange compilation problems ("strange" in that a few hours of Google-fu did not help), so I am turning to you to see if anyone sees how I can fix this.

I have already [checked that I have the required dependencies and followed the install instructions](http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/docs/INSTALL) as well as gone through [the build troubleshooting section of the FAQ](http://www-speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/manpages/srilm-faq.7.html).

## System Specifications

I have a pretty vanilla install of OS X, with some packages installed through homebrew. XCode 4.3.2 (latest version) is installed. Here are the other relevant system details.

### OS version

Mac OS X 10.7.4

### `gcc -v` printout

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.0.0/4.6.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.0.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.1/configure --enable-languages=fortran,c++
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.1 (GCC)
```

### `g++ -v` printout

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.0.0/4.6.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.0.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.1/configure --enable-languages=fortran,c++
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.1 (GCC)
```

### `uname -a` printout

```
$ uname -a
Darwin MacBook-Air.local 11.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.0: Mon Apr  9 19:32:15 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.26.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

## The error itself

The following is the end of the output produced by running `make World` from the srlim top-level directory. Everything up until this point compiles fine in any of the following circumstances:

- I run `make World` on its own.
- I run `make World MACHINE_TYPE=macosx`
- I run `make World MACHINE_TYPE=macosx-m64` (specific makefile for 64bit processors)
- I run `make World MACHINE_TYPE=macosx-m32` (specific makefile for 32bit processors)

And the error that pops up is always the same (shown below).

### `stderr` printout

```
$ make World

(...) # a bunch of stuff compiles with no errors or warnings

c++ -Wreturn-type -Wimplicit -DINSTANTIATE_TEMPLATES -DHAVE_ZOPEN  -I/usr/include -I. -I../../include -DHAVE_ZOPEN   -c -g -O2 -fno-common -o ../obj/macosx/LatticeIndex.o LatticeIndex.cc
LatticeIndex.cc:78:6: error: variable length array of non-POD element type
      'NBestWordInfo'
            makeArray(NBestWordInfo, roundedNgram, len + 1);
            ^
../../include/Array.h:93:33: note: expanded from macro 'makeArray'
# define makeArray(T, A, n)             T A[n]
                                           ^
LatticeIndex.cc:126:4: warning: data argument not used by format string
      [-Wformat-extra-args]
                        (float)ngram[0].start);
                        ^
LatticeIndex.cc:128:4: warning: data argument not used by format string
      [-Wformat-extra-args]
                        (float)(ngram[len-1].start + ngram[len-1].duration));
                        ^
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [../obj/macosx/LatticeIndex.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [release-libraries] Error 1
make: *** [World] Error 2
```

Any idea what could be going wrong? It seems to compile fine on some other people's macs in my department, and I've checked their makefiles for differences, but nothing popped up. No one here has any idea why the build fails, but we'd really appreciate it if you can help us out. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide me with! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to Apple using llvm-gcc/clang, which does not support variable length arrays. This problem can actually be addressed by modifying $SRILM/dstruct/src/Array.h, and has been noted and addressed in the upcoming release of `srilm`.

For the time being, on a mac, build `srilm` using g++ 4.2 instead, using the following command:

```
$ make MACHINE_TYPE=macosx-m64 CXX=g++-4.2 World
```

This builds `srilm` without problem on all my macs.